# I need to read all Email and Gmail programmatically

Tags: android, email, gmail

I need to read all e-mails programmatically. I want to get all the email content. Is it possible? Because I haven't found any appropriate solution to it

Comment: You have the email and the password of that account?

Comment: mail which are already config in android mobile i want to show user in my app listing of all inbox mail i want to listed.

Comment: @CommonsWare :: that ans code is not working there are many compile time error